# Method to return center items in a 2D array

Tags: c#, performance, mathematics

I wish to have code that returns the center items of a 2d grid. Because I need an average value. The code I came up with does what I want (see the unit tests beneath it). But I think the code is ugly and have the feeling it can be optimized. However, I do not see a way. Could this code be optimized by your mind? If so I like to learn how. I am not that concerned with performance, rather readability of the code. I think it is too clunky now.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetCenterItems<T>(this T[,] items)
    {
        var nrOfRows = items.GetLength(0);
        var nrOfColumns = items.GetLength(1);

        var itemsToReturn = new List<T>();
        if (nrOfRows.IsEven())
        {
            var startRow = nrOfRows / 2 - 1;
            if (nrOfColumns.IsEven())
            {
                var startColumn = nrOfColumns / 2 - 1;
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow, startColumn]);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow, startColumn + 1]);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow + 1, startColumn]);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow + 1, startColumn + 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                var columnNr = (nrOfColumns / 2);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow, columnNr]);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[startRow + 1, columnNr]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var rowNr = (nrOfRows / 2);
            if (nrOfColumns.IsEven())
            {
                var startColumn = (nrOfColumns / 2) - 1;
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[rowNr, startColumn]);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[rowNr, startColumn + 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                var columnNr = (nrOfColumns / 2);
                itemsToReturn.Add(items[rowNr, columnNr]);
            }
        }

        return itemsToReturn;
    }
```

And the unit tests

```
    [Test]
    public void CorrectCenterItemsAreReturnedForEvenRowsAndEvenColumns()
    {
        //Given
        var array = new [,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3, 4 },
            {5, 6, 7, 8 },
            {9, 10, 11, 12 },
            {13, 14, 15, 16 },
            {17, 18, 19, 20 },
            {21, 22, 23, 24 },
        };
        var expectedCenterItems = new[]
        {
            10, 11, 14, 15
        };

        //When
        var actualCenterItems = array.GetCenterItems();

        //Then
        actualCenterItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCenterItems);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CorrectCenterItemsAreReturnedForEvenRowsAndOddColumns()
    {
        //Given
        var array = new[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 25},
            {5, 6, 7, 8, 26 },
            {9, 10, 11, 12, 27 },
            {13, 14, 15, 16, 28 },
            {17, 18, 19, 20, 29 },
            {21, 22, 23, 24, 30 }
        };
        var expectedCenterItems = new[]
        {
            11, 15
        };

        //When
        var actualCenterItems = array.GetCenterItems();

        //Then
        actualCenterItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCenterItems);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CorrectCenterItemsAreReturnedForOddRowsAndOddColumns()
    {
        //Given
        var array = new[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 25},
            {5, 6, 7, 8, 26 },
            {9, 10, 11, 12, 27 },
            {13, 14, 15, 16, 28 },
            {17, 18, 19, 20, 29 }
        };
        var expectedCenterItems = new[]
        {
            11
        };

        //When
        var actualCenterItems = array.GetCenterItems();

        //Then
        actualCenterItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCenterItems);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CorrectCenterItemsAreReturnedForOddRowsAndEvenColumns()
    {
        //Given
        var array = new[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8 },
            {9, 10, 11, 12 },
            {13, 14, 15, 16 },
            {17, 18, 19, 20 }
        };
        var expectedCenterItems = new[]
        {
            10, 11
        };

        //When
        var actualCenterItems = array.GetCenterItems();

        //Then
        actualCenterItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCenterItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I'm not a fan of this at all. You're right that it's ugly, but we can fix that.

To boot, we're going to remove every single `if` statement here.

Let's talk about a quick mathematic property of what we're doing: we can get the midpoint of both sides of the array, then round up and/or down to find our values. Basically, if we get the midpoint, it will either be a decimal, or not. If it's a decimal, `floor(val)` and `ceil(val)` will give us the whole numbers on either side, and if it's not a decimal they'll just return the raw value.

```
var nrOfRows = items.GetLength(0);
var nrOfColumns = items.GetLength(1);
```

This is a good start, and I like what you did here. This is smart - put the things that are not the best to remember in variables, we're going to make one modification: divide by `2.0`:

```
var nrOfRows = (items.GetLength(0) -1) / 2.0;
var nrOfColumns = (items.GetLength(1) -1) / 2.0;
```

Fun fact: this will promote the `int` that `GetLength` returns to a `double`, then do floating-point division.

We want this, because now we can instance four quick variables using `Math.Floor` and `Math.Ceiling`:

```
var fRow = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfRows);
var lRow = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfRows);
var fCol = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfColumns);
var lCol = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfColumns);
```

Easy-peasy. The next part is simple: add each combination of `row, col` to a `List<Tuple<int, int>>`. This is so that we can use LINQ to quickly build our final result:

```
var cells = new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
    new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, fCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, lCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, fCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, lCol)
};
```

Ok, so this seems counter-intuitive, right? We're going to add *all* the coordinates, even though in the case of odd/odd, it'll be the same for each. Here's where LINQ comes in: using `.Distinct()` we can get *just* the unique values:

```
var resultCells = cells.Distinct();
```

That's *really* easy. So now, if it's just one point, they'll all be removed except for one. Next, we'll get the outputs at each point. This is, again, pretty easy:

```
return resultCells.Select(t => items[t.Item1, t.Item2]);
```

So our whole function is now:

```
var nrOfRows = items.GetLength(0) / 2.0;
var nrOfColumns = items.GetLength(1) / 2.0;
var fRow = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfRows);
var lRow = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfRows);
var fCol = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfColumns);
var lCol = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfColumns);

var cells = new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
    new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, fCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, lCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, fCol),
    new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, lCol)
};
var resultCells = cells.Distinct();
return resultCells.Select(t => items[t.Item1, t.Item2]);
```

We can also do the whole last part in one pass:

```
return
    new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
        new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, fCol),
        new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, lCol),
        new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, fCol),
        new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, lCol)
    }
    .Distinct()
    .Select(t => items[t.Item1, t.Item2]);
```

If you have access to C#7.0 and the `ValueTuple` NuGet package, the `.Select` is simpler:

```
.Select((y, x) => items[y, x])
```

Now we have eliminated *all* of our duplication, and we've made it clean, readable, and simple. There's not much to be inferred here, and it's easy to manage.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetCenterItems<T>(this T[,] items)
{
    var nrOfRows = (items.GetLength(0) - 1) / 2.0;
    var nrOfColumns = (items.GetLength(1) - 1) / 2.0;
    var fRow = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfRows);
    var lRow = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfRows);
    var fCol = (int)Math.Floor(nrOfColumns);
    var lCol = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfColumns);

    return
        new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
            new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, fCol),
            new Tuple<int, int>(fRow, lCol),
            new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, fCol),
            new Tuple<int, int>(lRow, lCol)
        }
        .Distinct()
        .Select(t => items[t.Item1, t.Item2]);
}
```

Comment: You can make it even better/shorter by using tuples with named properties, so instead of `List<Tuple<int, int>>` make it `List<(int Row, int Col)>` and initlize with just `(fRow, fCol)` without `new Tuple`. The query will become cleaner too: `things[t.Row, t.Col]`

Comment: @t3chb0t Absolutely, feel free to drop that in as an edit if you would like (or alternate answer), I'm unfamiliar with C#7.0 (basically quit using C# as-of-late), so I'm curious to see what that solution looks like, and I'm not the best to write it. :)

Comment: Nice answer.  The only thing is `nrOfRows` suggests a row count, and your changes produce the row midpoint.  Thus I would name it `rowMidPt` and `colMidPt` to provide a more meaningful (or less confusing) name.